# How do I find and copy an arbitrary list of files in terminal?

Tags: command-line, find, copy

I'm trying to get my head around finding files in terminal at the moment. I've found a lot of answers about how to find files to a specific pattern, such as files ending in a certain extension, or from a certain timeframe, etc.

What I've been trying to figure out, though, is how to find and copy multiple arbitrary files, like a list of specific files.

Say, for example, I have the following folders and files

`/Documents/Folder_1/` with contents:

```
file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt
```

`/Documents/Folder_2/` with contents:

```
file5.txt file6.txt file7.txt
```

`/Documents/Folder_3/` with contents:

```
file8.txt, file9.txt
```

and what I want to do is to make a new folder called `Folder_4` and copy `file2.txt`, `file5.txt` and `file9.txt` to that new folder.

Is there any way to do this through terminal?

What I've tried to do is to make a text list of the file names and call it something like list.txt, e.g.

```
file2.txt
file5.txt
file9.txt
```

and loading that text file into the Find command, for example like this:

```
find /home/usr/Documents -name $cat list.txt
```

with the thinking that I would then feed the output to either a text list or a copy command, but this doesn't seem to work.

I'm wondering if there is any way to find multiple arbitrary files through the Find command, or am I thinking about this in the wrong way?

EDIT: Just wanted to say thanks for the answers and summarise the way that I ended up approaching this problem. I especially appreciate that someone explained to me that the find command is not designed to accept more than one input without the -o flag, it made me feel a bit less stupid for not being able to figure it out!

What I ended up doing was to make a little shell script and ask for user input and use an array and a for loop to iterate through the list.

Basically the script that I ended up with is more or less like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

#take user input
echo "Please enter list of filenames to search"
read list
echo "Please enter the folder path to search"
read path
echo "Please enter the destination folder path"
read destination

#use inputted list as input for array, and then use a for loop to find each item on list one by one
array=($list)
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    find "$path" -iname "i" -exec cp '{}' "$destination" \;
done
```

Comment: This is very useful. Although, I don't seem to make it work. In the end, the terminal says: `logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.` But no file was actually copied in the selected folder.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the `find` command's `-name` predicate only accepts a single pattern. If you want to search for multiple files by name you'd need to chain them with the `-o` (logical `OR`) operator - something like:

```
find Documents/ \( -name "file2.txt" -o -name "file5.txt" -o -name "file9.txt" \) -print
```

This makes it tricky to construct the search programmatically from a list; the closest I can come to your attempted command is:

1. read the list into a shell array

   ```
   mapfile -t files < list.txt
   ```
2. use the bash shell's `printf` to construct the predicate list

   ```
   printf -- '-name "%s" -o ' "${files[@]}"
   ```
3. use `eval` to evaluate the resulting command string

There's a wrinkle here inasmuch as if we use `printf`'s format re-use feature to construct the list in this way, we're left with a 'dangling' `-o`; we can work around this by terminating the list with a `-false` test (since `-o -false` is a Boolean no-op) so that our final predicate string becomes

```
"\( $(printf -- '-name "%s" -o ' "${files[@]}") -false \)"
```

---

Putting it all together - given

```
$ tree dir
dir
├── Folder_1
│   ├── file1.txt
│   ├── file2.txt
│   ├── file3.txt
│   └── file4.txt
├── Folder_2
│   ├── file5.txt
│   ├── file6.txt
│   └── file7.txt
└── Folder_3
    ├── file8.txt
    └── file9.txt

3 directories, 9 files
```

and

```
$ cat list.txt
file2.txt
file5.txt
file9.txt
```

then

```
$ mapfile -t files < list.txt

$ eval find dir/ "\( $(printf -- '-name "%s" -o ' "${files[@]}") -false \)" -print
dir/Folder_1/file2.txt
dir/Folder_2/file5.txt
dir/Folder_3/file9.txt
```

---

To copy files instead of just listing them, you could then do

```
$ mkdir newdir
$ eval find dir/ "\( $(printf -- '-name "%s" -o ' "${files[@]}") -false \)" -exec cp -t newdir/ -- {} +
```

resulting in

```
$ tree newdir
newdir
├── file2.txt
├── file5.txt
└── file9.txt

0 directories, 3 files
```

*Note: the* `eval` *command is powerful and potentially open to abuse: use with care.*

---

In practice, given that you appear to want to find only a small number of files, the [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) approach would be to accept the performance hit of multiple `find` calls and just use a loop:

```
while read -r f; do
  find dir/ -name "$f" -exec cp -v -- {} newdir/ \;
done < list.txt
```

or even using `xargs`

```
xargs -a list.txt -n1 -I@ find dir/ -name @ -exec cp -v -- {} newdir/ \;
```

Comment: thanks very much for the detailed reply. I did a bit of digging after posting the question and came upon a solution fairly similar to what you described!

Comment: (didn't mean to hit enter on the previous comment)... Basically I made a little script which prompts the user to enter the list of filenames separated by spaces, and then used that as the input to an array.

basically the script was to the effect of:
    
    echo "Please enter your list"
    read list
    echo "please enter the path to search in"
    read path
    echo "please enter the path to the destination folder
    read destination

    array=($list)
    for i in "${array[@]}"
    do
        find "$path" -iname "$i" -exec cp '{}' "$destination" \;
    done

Comment: @david I have added a couple of KISS suggestions - if using multiple `find` calls is acceptable

Answer (score 0):

Still trying to figure out your question in the clearest way.

Are you trying to find some specific files in a directory ?
If yes and there is a pattern that you could use regular expressions to find them then use `find <directory> -regex "your_regex"`  and if there is no pattern you need the specify the filenames which you're looking for.You can use the python script below to copy your files.

```py
import shutil
import os

list = [file1.txt, file2.txt] # replace with your file list.
destination = "your_destination" # replace with your destination.
directory = os.getcwd() # replace os.getcwd() with your directory.

for dirpath, dirname, filenames in os.walk(directory, topdown='true'):
    for file in filenames :
        if file in list :
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(dirpath, file), destination)
```

If the above isn't your case then I suggest using this :

```
find <somewhere> -name "something" | xargs cp -t <your_destination>
```

Answer (score 0):

The bash script below, if executed from within the top level directory ( say from your `~/Documents` folder ) , will create new directory and copy/move the files you want. By default it only echoes found files, so that the user can check if this is the result they'd like. Note: replace `echo` with `cp` to copy or `mv`  to move.

List of files is assigned to `regex` variable with `\|` separator (which for `grep` means logical or statement)

`copy_files.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
new_dir="./dir4"
[ -d "$new_dir" ] ||  mkdir "$new_dir"
regex="file1\|file3\|file6"
find . -print0 | while IFS= read -d $'\0' line;
do
    if grep -q "$regex" <<< $line
    then
       filename=$(basename "$line")
       printf "%s\n" "Found $filename"
       echo "$line" "$new_dir"/"$filename"
       # Replace echo with cp for copying,
       # or mv for moving
    fi   
done
```

```
bash-4.3$ ./copy_files.sh 
Found file6
./dir3/file6 ./dir4/file6
Found file3
./dir1/file3 ./dir4/file3
Found file1
./dir1/file1 ./dir4/file1
```

As you can see above, the script reports what file was found and where it would copy it or move , for instance in last line it would copy/move `./dir1/file1` to `./dir4/file1` if this was actually using `cp` or `mv` and not just `echo`

Comment: Suggestion: Stick the `grep` between `find` and the loop: `find … | grep -z "$regex" | while …`.