# Search for multiple patterns from a file using find command

Tags: command-line, find

There is an option to use `grep -f MY_FILE` to let it search for patterns taken from a file, instead of being specified directly on the command line.

Is there an option to do something similar with the `find` command and let it read the patterns to search from an input file?

Comment: I don't get it. What exactly do you want to pass to find? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @RoVo text file' like I passed text file bar to grep in my example.

Comment: So instead of saying `find /somewhere -name 'PATTERN'`, you want to read multiple PATTERNs from a file, line by line?

Comment: Indeed @Byte Commander, like in the example with grep -f

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find` doesn't seem to have such capabilities built in, but you can use `xargs` to construct multiple `find` commands using arguments from a file, like:

```
xargs -a patterns.txt -I% find Pictures/ -name %
```

where `patterns.txt` would be a list of patterns suitable for the `-name` filter, one pattern per line. Pay attention that you don't have leading/trailing spaces in there, as they would be included in the pattern. An example:

```
*.jpg
2018-06-*
*foo*
unicorn.png
```

> **Note:** While this answer looks quite easy and elegant, it got correctly pointed out in the comments that it has a few downsides:
>
> Performance is not too great for large folders or many patterns, as it will run `find` once per pattern in your file, causing it to repeatedly scan the whole search folder.
>
> Because of that, also if you have multiple patterns which could potentially overlap (like `*.jpg` and `*foo*`), files matching more than one pattern will appear that many times in the result. If you're only printing the names anyway, you could pipe the output through `sort -u` to remove duplicates, but if you e.g. remove those results or run any `-exec` commands on them, this may be more undesirable.
>
> If any of these downsides are a problem for your use case, maybe better go for one of the alternative answers.

Explanation of the command:

- `xargs` will read a list of arguments and use them to construct and run a new command line.
- `-a patterns.txt` tells it to read from that file instead of the standard input.
- `-I%` tells it to not simply append the arguments it read to the end of the command line, but to replace the `%` character in the command line you supplied with one argument. This implies creating and running one separate command per input argument.
- `find Pictures/ -name %` is the command line into which we want to insert the arguments, replacing the `%`. You don't need quoting here, because `xargs` will take care that each argument it inserts will be treated as single token and not get split on its own. You can of course replace the `Pictures/` with your own search directory and also use a different and/or more filters other than just `-name`. Because we use the insert option, you can also append actions like `-exec ...` to the end of the command.

Comment: Won't this be terribly slow with a long list of words, running find many times? Or is find clever enough to reuse the results from before?

Comment: @RoVo Your argument is correct, it would run `find` once per line in the pattern file, scanning through the whole search directory each time. It's not the best variant if you have a huge search folder or big list of arguments due to this, but it's surely easier to write and remember for smaller tasks. If performance is an issue, your regex solution should probably be preferred.

Comment: also if you have `*.jpg` and `*foo*` as patterns, and a file called `foo.jpg`, it will be found twice.

Comment: Tnx @ RoVo @Byte Commander. Performance matters for me. And your answers are more neat than there: https://askubuntu.com/questions/837247/how-do-i-find-and-copy-an-arbitrary-list-of-files-in-terminal

Answer (score 4):

You can simply create a regex from the contents of your file using `paste -sd'|' bar`.

```
find ~/foo -regextype egrep -regex "^.*/($(paste -sd'|' bar))$"
```

The regex will be `"^.*/(a|b)$"`

Comment: I'm getting illegal variable name, trying to run it. Any suggestions: why? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not too recently, I've made an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1044418/295286) that combines multiple patterns using `-regex` flag in `find`. Based on that, we can make a small script or function to do that same job, but build up the list of patterns from file.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

read_file(){
    local full_pattern=""
    while IFS= read -r pattern; do
        if [ -z "$full_pattern"  ];then
            full_pattern="$pattern"
            continue
        fi
        full_pattern="$full_pattern\|$pattern"
    done < "$1"
    echo "$full_pattern"
}

fp=$(read_file "$1" )
find "$2" -type f -regex ".*\($fp\).*$"
```

What this does:

- we call script as `findf.sh input.txt /etc`, where first positional parameter is the file with patters, and second - directory where to search. GNU find assumes `.` directory if directory argument is omitted , so `$2` isn't erequired.
- The function `read_file` reads the input file that is first positional parameter to script. This builds up a pattern for `-regex` flag.
- This pattern is echoed back to "main" block of the script, and saved to `fp` variable, and that gets passed into the `find` command.